# Sumar contenido de filas de un DataGridView y despegarlo en un Textbox

Tags: c#, datagrid

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación para el control de etiquetas para la empresa donde trabajo. Estoy trabajando con un DataGridView el cual almacena los datos introducidos de los primeros Textbox como muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hace hasta el momento de presionar el botón "insertar" agrega una nueva fila con los valores dados en cada TextBox.

Lo que pretendo hacer es que también al momento de presionar el botón "insertar" se vayan sumando por columna y mostrar el resultado total de la suma de cada columna en cada uno de los Textbox que les corresponde.

No se si existe alguna manera para eso que pueda ser de mi ayuda. Saludos.

Gracias.

Comment: No logro comprender tu pregunta, quieres que mientras vayas agregando mas filas se vaya sumando el valor con la demás que ya están? es decir, ahora se tendría que sumar 2+2+1 para la primera columna?

Comment: Hola SSV ITT, perdon si no pude explicarme bien, tome la captura de pantalla para dar un ejemplo, pero tomando la captura  es que ya estuvieran sumadas 2+2+1 y mostradas en el Textbox de total  y si insertamos otra columna se sume.

Comment: Hola @EzequieLopez entiendo que usas los textbox de arriba para crear una nueva fila y al darle al boton insertar añade esta al datagrid y ademas realiza la suma por columnas y mete el resultado en los textbox de abajo?

Comment: Hola @ElGerar lo siento al momento de redactar mi pregunta confundí filas con columnas, ya la edite, pero si tienes razon, lo que pretendo hacer es realizar la sumas por columnas y meter ese resultado en los textbox de abajo. Saludos

Comment: Ok, ahora te añado una respuesta

Comment: Cual es el DataSource de tu Grid, con eso podria poner algun ejemplo para poner el total!

Comment: Por ejemplo: 17: 2, 3,4 ; 17.5: 3,5,6; 18: 3,4,7; 18.5: 5,6,13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo en código de como sumar los valores de las celdas de cada columna

```
//Realizo la suma de cada columna        
for (int numColumna = 0; numColumna < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; numColumna++)
        {
           var sumTotal= 0;           
           foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
           {

               sumTotal += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[numColumna].Value);
           }

           textBox1.Text = sumTotal.ToString();//Aqui en cada iteración del for deberia ser el textbox correspondiente
        }
```

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.

Comment: Una pregunta solamente, ¿tengo que hacer un "for" para cada Columna?

Comment: ¡¡Ya supe como meter todo en una, solo declare diferentes variables, saludos, eres un crack!!

Comment: Tienes que realizar la suma por columna, puedes recorrerlas con un for o crear una función y pasarle el numero de columna

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirva. Un saludo